# What is a an alternative for "bring" in bring a new perspective?

Tags: synonyms

In the sentence:

Studying the published articles on this artwork will allow me to bring a new perspective.

What is an alternative for "bring" or even "perspective"?

Comment: Will you be bringing the new perspective to a group that's working on a project that will hopefully benefit from it, or are you talking about bringing the new perspective to yourself as an individual for your own enjoyment/appreciation of the art?

Comment: I want to bring a new perspective by not writing what has already been written. Even though it is not clear from this sentence, it is clear from the context of the sentence in my essay.

Comment: To clarify, the sentence can also be: "Reading what has already been written on this artwork will allow me to bring a new perspective by avoiding existing perspectives."

Comment: ahh ok, I see. Reading the other articles isn't designed to inspire your new perspective, but rather to insure that whatever perspective you end up developing and bringing is in fact new.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for clarifying what I am trying to say :)

Comment: Provide a new perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*see in a new light*

> Studying the published articles on this artwork will allow me to see it in a new light.

Sort of a pun.

Answer (score 1):

Usher seems a proper word.
USHER
verb
1.
show or guide (someone) somewhere.
"a waiter ushered me to a table"
synonyms:   escort, accompany, help, assist, take, show, see, lead, show someone the way, lead the way, conduct, guide, steer, pilot, shepherd, convoy
"he ushered him to a window seat"
2.
cause or mark the start of something new.
"the railways ushered in an era of cheap mass travel"
synonyms:   herald, mark the start of, signal, announce, give notice of, ring in, show in, set the scene for, pave the way for, clear the way for, open the way for, smooth the path of; 
so you can say "ushered in a new perspective" as well. Though bring is more common.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, “**provide**” goes very well with “a new perspective,” and [this Ngram report](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=present+a+new+perspective%2Cprovide+a+new+perspective%2Cbring+a+new+perspective%2Coffer+a+new+perspective&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpresent%20a%20new%20perspective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprovide%20a%20new%20perspective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbring%20a%20new%20perspective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coffer%20a%20new%20perspective%3B%2Cc0) puts it ahead of *bring* and two other options that I considered: *offer* (my favorite) and *present*.
It’s perhaps interesting to note, however, that the Ngram seems to indicate that my favorite (**offer**) has been gaining ground on *provide* since 2000.

The main reason that I prefer *offer* (and even *present*) over both *provide* and *bring* is that it (they) sound/s a bit more humble, a bit less authoritatively pompous, to me at least, than *provide* (and even *bring*).

Of course, regardless of the verb you choose, the unspoken notion of ...

> “[provide/offer/bring/present …] **for your consideration**”

... will be implied, but personally I prefer, as perhaps your audience might, to have something offered or presented to me over having it provided or brought to me:

> Studying the published articles on this artwork will allow me to
>   offer/present a new perspective [on it].

---

For a possible way of replacing both “bring” and “perspective,” borrowing from Aparente001’s good answer, you could consider [“**shed [a] new light**”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shed+new+light%2C+shed+a+new+light&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshed%20new%20light%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshed%20a%20new%20light%3B%2Cc0), but you’d definitively need to add “on it,” whereas you could probably omit “on it” after *perspective* (and as the Ngram report indicates, it would be more idiomatic without the “a”):

> Studying the published articles on this artwork will allow me to [shed
>   new light
>   on](https://books.google.com/books?id=vy9OCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&dq=%22shed+new+light%22+%22new+perspective%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieyKzCu6jQAhVB7oMKHcsCDAgQ6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=%22shed%20new%20light%22%20%22new%20perspective%22&f=false) it.

(example of “shed new light on” used together  with “new perspective” from *Revivals, Awakenings, and Reform* by William G. McLoughlin, via *GoogleBooks*)